# Double Integral Involving Two Circles

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, circles

**Problem:**

> Find $\iint_\limits{D} x\cdot dA$, where $D$ is the region inside the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, but outside the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

I was working on the above problem and was if my setup is correct.

I would first integrate $x$ from $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}+1$. Then integrate from $0$ to $1$ wrt $y*$. (I get a solution of $\frac{\pi}{2} + 1$. But when I was inspecting my picture, I get a feeling that my setup isn't quite correct...

Thank you!

Comment: You can see the problem right? The circles intersect but the curves $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}+1$ never do

Comment: There is an easier way to do this but if you are using cartesian coordinates, have you first found the intersection of both circles?  Between $y$ values of intersection points, what you have set up for $x$ is correct. But above intersection point on positive $y$ side and below intersection point on negative $y$ side, your lower and upper bounds of $x$ will be both on the circle $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Comment: Polar is definitely the way to go here

Comment: @MatthewPilling, I was thinking of using polar at first. Do the double integral for the right circle and subtract the double integral of the intersection. But I am stuck on how to do the double integral of x for the intersection of the two circles.

Comment: Instead of doing it in pieces, note that the polar equation for the two curves are $r=1$ and $r=2\cos\theta$. The intersection of these two curves have polar coordinates of $(1,\pm\frac{\pi}{3})$. Hence the desired region is represented by $1\leq r\leq 2\cos\theta$, $-\frac{\pi}{3}\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{3}$.